# How to Interfacing SWI Prolog to the Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, prolog, swi-prolog, interfacing

I have a program that interfacing SWI-Prolog in Visual Studio. Previously, I used VS2010 (XP) and everything works fine. Then I upgrade my VS to become VS2012 (Win7) and now I have a problem in my code.

When it comes to the following code:

```
PlEngine.Initialize(param);
```

it always gives me the following exception message:

```
The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
```

Can anybody spot what mistake that I made or if possible some modification that I have to do, due to the upgrading process?

Additional information regarding my code:

- I used the most updated swiPLCs library (version: 1.1.60301.0)
- my 'param' in my code above is: string[] param = { "-q", "-f", @"c:\program files (x86)\pl\"};
- I have set the path environment variable to: c:\program files (x86)\pl\ and c:\program files (x86)\pl\bin
- I have this setting in my code:  Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("SWI_HOME_DIR", Global.g_prologLocation);
- I had the reference to: swiPLcs.dll
- I already tried to use the SWIProlog 64 bit, but I still have the same problem

Any help is really appreciated.

Many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally got the answer myself.
Unlike VS2010, In VS2012 it seems that you have to add SWI-Prolog package into VS2012.
So add SWI.Prolog package using Nuget.
How?

See: https://nuget.org/packages/SWI.Prolog

And VS2012 will recognize the SWI.Prolog now.

Thanks anyway